# Subclass/Extend UIView so all other Views (UIImageView, UITextField ...) inherit upon creation

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, subclass, extension-methods

what is the suggested approach when I want to add a functionality to UIView so all views inside my app get those? As a matter of fact I need to add some stored properties too so an Extension is not possible. Since I need to deal with Textfields, ImageViews, Views (and who knows what else will come) I dont want to subclass every each of the too add that functionality, so the goal would be to make a subclass of UIView and all my controls (if its possible) get that functionality out of the box.

With an extension it would be easy, but as I said, I need to store some stuff too, so is this  goal achievable with a subclass? Or what would be the right approach (maybe there is a third option)

Thanks

Comment: Hey there, I saw a similar question 2-3 years ago and it was answered -> please look better at SO.. I think the key was to use this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1441536-class_setsuperclass  method...
however you should be careful with this since for example 'UITextField' super is 'UIControl'-- also it seems to be deprecatred also

Comment: yes, smt like this would be perfect, but obviously the killed this option. I will search if there is smt similar to this for swift

Comment: There's a yucky way to do it at runtime with associated properties in objective-c, but yuck.  It would be better to talk about why you think you need to add properties to those views and consider some alternatives.  As a general principal, a bunch of views are for presenting and editing a model, and it's usually that model we try to enrich with properties.

Comment: It is mostly regarding transformation. I want all my views when they are in a special environment (means when the parent is special) to have all transformation capabilities (dragging, rotating, scaling ...). And I thought it would be good to do that once inside UIView, and not for every View in particular (bcz the code is actually 90% similar for UIImageView, UITextView ...). And therefore I would also need to store some of the transformation information. But  it seems like I will have to do it for every View Type i want to support ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR; You can't do this and you will need to subclass each UI element that you want to introduce new properties to.

You can't do this (without access to the source code) as you would effectively be changing the class inheritance tree by injecting your own class between `UIView` and its subclasses.

Consider the implications if a language allowed this:

- `Class A` defines a property, `a`
- `Class B`inherits from `Class A` and defines a property `b`, which is fine because `Class A` does not have this property.
- `Class C` inherits from `Class B` and has both `a` and `b` properties.

Now, what could happen if you could 'inject' `Class A1` somehow 'below' `Class A`?

- `Class A1` could define a property, `b`, which is fine because `Class A` does not have this property
- `Class B` now has a problem though, because *its* `b` clashes with the superclass `b`
- `Class C` has a multiple-inheritance diamond-problem with property `b`

Of course, you only intend to add properties that don't clash (although you can't know this because you don't know of all possible subclass implementations) and don't need the subclasses to access your property, so the multiple inheritance
 isn't an issue, but if such a feature were in a language, these potential issues would need to be addressed because you can't rely on everyone having the same intentions as you.

Comment: I actually wanted to go deeper on this, wrote some stuff too, but since its not possible I  decided to delete it bcz it would be a waste of time to discuss it :)  thanks for the answer and the clarification

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you define a protocol and provide default implementations in the protocol extension, then have UIView conform to that protocol? Here is an example:

```
protocol MyProto {
    var someVar: Bool { get set }
    func someFunc() -> Void
}

extension MyProto {
    var someVar: Bool {
        get {
            // provide default implementation
            return true
        }
        set {

        }
    }

    func someFunc() -> Void {
        // provide common implementation
    }
}

extension UIView: MyProto {}
```

You can also use the `where` clause to constrain the default behaviour for a type.

```
extension MyProto where Self: UIControl {
    var someVar: Bool {
        get {
            return isUserInteractionEnabled
        }
        set {
            isUserInteractionEnabled = newValue
        }
    }
}

extension MyProto where Self: UITextField {
    var someVar: Bool {
        get {
            return isFirstResponder
        }
        set {
            newValue ? becomeFirstResponder() : resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bcz this part is not valid inside an extension "var someVar: Bool"

Comment: How is it not valid?

Comment: But I still need to store some value inside "someVar". I need a setter too, and then you get the error

Comment: Simply make the property Settable in the protocol definition. I just updated my answer to fit your use case.

Comment: maybe I dont see it, but I still dont get it (even though I am really surprised what you can do with protocols in swift). But to point it out, I have a property that stores the last position of the view (so last time view was dragged), where/and how would I store that value in your setup?

Comment: @AhmedOnawale there is a big difference between a settable computed property and a settable stored property.

Comment: Of course. The settable computed property would only be useful when mutating existing properties on UIView, not adding new properties. A subclass with the custom array is the way to go.